# Python Convert String into Integer by lines?

Tags: python

Let's say that I have a Python string like this:

```
Some first text:  2342
Another line here:  284
Maybe third line: 458
And forth line: 199
```

And I want to create 4 integer variables from this string such that var = (whatever number in line 1). And var2 = (whatever number in line 2).. And so on.

How is it possible?

Comment: Yeah it is possible first use `split` and `int` for getting your numbers then use `dictionary` for storing them .

Comment: Why don't you try yourself first, and if you did then show us the code that you tried with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all numbers in an array:

```
s = '''\
Some first text:  2342
Another line here:  284
Maybe third line: 458
And forth line: 199'''

print [int(l.split(':')[1]) for l in s.split('\n')]
```

Output:

```
[2342, 284, 458, 199]
```

And then the first element of the array will correspond to the first line etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    words = somestring.split()
    for i in range(len(words)):
        try:
            locals()['int_%s'%(i)] = int(words[i])
        exept:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make with `for` loop and `is_digit` method.

like this:

```
# let's guess input text is called TEXT.
TEXT = '''\
Some first text:  2342
Another line here:  284
Maybe third line: 458
And forth line: 199'''

# we can make like this:
splited_TEXT = TEXT.split('\n')
# make new(wanted) dictionary
new_dict = {}

# then use for loop:
for num, sentence in enumerate(splited_TEXT):
    for word in sentence.split(' '): # split by space
        if word.is_digit: # check if word is digit
            new_dict[num] = word
            continue
print(new_dict)
```

Then you can check {0:2342, 1:284 ...}

Answer (score 0):

I found that this simple line works:

```
[int(s) for s in TEXT.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

for TEXT as above.

Comment: Right, but this doesn't answer the second part i.e. creating the variables. More generalized solution would be nicer as I don't believe OP will have knowledge of the number count (although maybe it's just a number-per-line thingy). :)

Comment: For the 4 numbers, it would look like this: var1, var2, var3, var4  = [int(s) for s in TEXT.split() if s.isdigit()]